# How can I convert time into percent using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, momentjs

I need to convert a complete hour by hour into %, but I am not sure if moment is able to do that.

Eg.:
I do have

```
let start = 08:00:00
// until
let end = 09:00:00
```

This is equal: 100%, but I receive an information from frontend value:

```
let data = 08:25:40
```

I need to know how much percent of hour have been passed from start, until the end.

I do have an workaround, but this is a little bit like a trick not a real solution.

Does anybody knows if JS has a library that can do this for me, easily?

Thanks.

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Count the time difference from start to end  and from start to your data in milisecond, then do simple math. Use [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) method to calculate the time difference in milliseconds.

Here is a similar code snippet:

```
let start = 08:00:
let end = 09:00:00
let data = 08:25:40

const mStart = moment(start)
const mEnd = moment(end)
const mData = moment(data)

const percentile = 100.0 * mData.diff(mStart)/mEnd.diff(mStart)
```